# Dynamic Column Header in Angular Ag-Grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am trying to create AG-grid (NOT UI Grid)where the column headers have to be loaded dynamically from the JSON response. I have tried many ways but I could not accomplish so any help is very much appreciable.

**Grid – The format which I am expecting** (Image attached)

In the grid, the first two columns Part No and Part Name are fixed. The remaining columns are dynamic where the column header is not decided before initializing the grid.

I’m ready to change the JSON format to make the grid format

**JSON Format**

```
[  
   {  
      "partNo":"P00001",
      "partName":"AAAAA",
      "periodList":[  
         {  
            "period":"Jan-15",
            "periodValue":"267"
         },
 {  
     "period":"Feb-15",
     "periodValue":"347"
 }
]
},
]
```

[AG GRID Sample Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcdvs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of angular is limited, but I am will attempt to help (disclaimer:) Though, I am sure there is an easier method, I hope this one helps

```
//For convenience, lets call your dataset partSales.

//1st get dynamic columns
var myDynamicColumns = getMyDynamicColumns(partsales);
//2nd format data to make period data have a unique name. 
//Note the periodValue will be assigned to its period e.g. 'Jan-15':'267' 
//This should match the columnDefs field value. e.g. field: 'Jan-15'
var myData = myDataFormatter(partsales);
//fixed columns
var gridOColDefs = [
            {
                field: 'partNo',
                enableCellEdit: false,
                headerName: 'Part No',
            },
            {
                field: 'partName',
                enableCellEdit: false,
                headerName: 'Part Name',
                cellClass: 'text-right',
                width: 45,
                headerGroup: 'Farm'
            }].concat(myDynamicColumns);
];

//Define you grid options
var gridOptimizerOptions = {
    pinnedColumnCount:2,
    columnDefs: myDynamicColumns,
    rowData: myData
};


//Returns an list of dynamic column definitions
function getMyDynamicColumns(partsales){

    var columnFields = [];

    //loop though parts
    _.each(partSales, function(singlePartSale){

        //loop through periods
        _.each(singlePartSale.periodList, function(period){
            var periodTitle = period.period;

            //Do something to make sure the column definition has not already been added. The conditional syntax below is not valid.
            if(periodTitle is not in columnFields){
                columnFields.push(
                {
                    //You will have to flush this out. You may need to loop through you data and give each period an unique name. 
                    field: [periodTitle], 
                    headerName: [periodTitle],
                    width: 50                
                });
            } //end condition
        }); //periods loop
    });//end parts loop

    //Return new column defs so they can be concattinated to the fixed column Definitions
    return columnFields;
}

function myDataFormatter(partSales){
    var newDataList = [];
    _.each(partSales, function(partSale){
        var newData = {
            partNo = partSale.partNo,
            partName = partSale.partName
        }
        _.each(partSale.periodList, function(singlePeriod){ 
                var newField = singlePeriod.period;          
                newData.push([newField] = singlePeriod.periodValue);
        });
        newDataList.push(newData);
    })
    return newDataList;
})


// so your data should look like this from the data formatter function.
[{
    'partNo':"P00001",
    'partName':'AAAAA',
    'Jan-15':"267",
    'Feb-15':"347",
    ...and so on.
},
{
    'partNo':"P00002",
    'partName':'AAAB',
    'Jan-15':"421",
    'Feb-15':"2",
    ...and so on.
}]
```

Comment: Faced exactly the same issue, any other simole way to do that?